# Obtaining an array of objects from fetch request

Tags: ios, swift

I have an object called Projects that I save to core data. I then add multiple projects to core data. I want to retrieve those objects as an array from core data. The following code gets this error:

> -[NSAsynchronousFetchResult mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
    var uploadPhotos : NSMutableArray? = []

var activeProject : String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    projectPicker.dataSource = self
    projectPicker.delegate = self

    isInSegmentPhoto = true


    //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Project")
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Project.fetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Project", in: sharedDelegate.managedObjectContext)

    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let result = try self.sharedDelegate.managedObjectContext.execute(fetchRequest)
        print(result)

        projects = result.mutableCopy() as! [Project]



    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }


}
```

When I run the program it prints out the list of projects, but crashes on the first line of the do-catch.

Answer (score 1):

Please, please use Swift native types, `NSMutableArray` has no type information.

```
var projects = [Project]()
...
projects = try defaultManagedObjectContext().fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Project]
```

Since the fetch request is clearly a `Project` request you can safely unwrap the result.

`mutableCopy()` causes the error, because `NSFetchRequestResult`(the umbrella protocol of all possible result types) does not respond to that method.

Comment: Sorry, coming from objective-c and still getting used to Swift. I edited the code, but I am still receiving the same error. I think it may have something to do with the fetchRequest and entityDescription

Comment: Remove `mutableCopy()` (which is the actual reason of the error). Swift arrays with `var` are mutable for free. And don't edit the question with the solution. It confuses others.

Comment: The code I put up in the edit works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Harry Once again: **Don't edit the question with the solution**. The question is now meaningless, because the code does not throw the error.

Comment: Did not see you suggest that the first time my bad. I edited the post to the original code and submitted my working code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I was using the wrong method. Replace execute with fetch.

```
self.sharedDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```